# php curl download file from url

Tags: php, curl

I have local wamp server in my windows machine.
Inside the www directory i have folder called project. c:www/project/index.php.

And next same path, i have directory to save the destination location c:www/project/downloads.

when i was run my localhost http://localhost:8089/curl/index.php

I have following error, error image attached here.
[image: php curl method download file]

This is my code:

```
      <?php class download {

    const URL_MAX_LENGTH = 3000;

    protected function cleanUrl($url) {
        if(isset($url)){
            if(!empty($url)){
                if(strlen($url) < self::URL_MAX_LENGTH) {
                    return strip_tags($url);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    //is url
    protected function isUrl($url) {
    $url = $this->cleanUrl($url);
    if(isset($url)) {
        if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED)) {
            return $url;
        }
    }
}

    protected function returnExtension($url) {
        if($this->isUrl($url)) {
           $end = end(preg_split("/[.]+/", $url));
           if(isset($end)) {
                return $end;
            }
        }
    }

    public function downloadFile($url) {
        if($this->isUrl($url)) {
           $extension = $this->returnExtension($url);
           if($extension) {
               echo $url;
               $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
            $return = curl_exec($ch);

            $destination = "downloads/file.$extension";
            $file = fopen($destination, "w+");
            fputs($file, $return);
           }
            if(fclose($file)){
                echo "File Download";

            }

        }

    }

    }


$obj = new Download();
if(isset($_POST['url'])) { $url = $_POST['url']; } ?>

<form action="http://localhost:8089/curl/index.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="url" maxlength="3000"/>
    <input type="submit" value="download"/>

</form>

<?php if(isset($url)) { $obj->downloadFile($url); } ?>
```

could you please some one help on this ?

Many Thanks,
Palani

Answer (score 2):

Replace below line at the returnExtension function

```
$end = end(preg_split("/[.]+/", $url));
```

with

```
$result = preg_split("/[.]+/", $url);       
$end = end($result);
```

Comment: HI Jay, Thanks lot your post, now it is working file :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line:

```
$end = end(preg_split("/[.]+/", $url));
```

to

```
$urlParts = preg_split("/[.]+/", $url);
$end = end($urlParts);
```

this is not really an error, but a strict standard notice. 
It's because php want only variables passed by reference, and the return of preg_split is not a variable.

Comment: Can yo please tell how your answer is different from @Jay Gosai  ??